# MXF corrupted and how to fix it

Tags: ffmpeg

Using FFmpeg on macOS.

I have two MXF files (one recording that spanned across two files with 41 GB on the 1st and 13 GB on the 2nd)

- Metadata on the second seems incomplete or corrupted.
- 2nd file would not ingest or play in any DAW, Player or EncodingSoftware.
- I tried everything I could find on the web

Comment: Upload it to pastebin or similar and share link

Comment: What makes you believe it's incomplete or corrupted? Are you getting any errors? If you have an error log, please add it to your question. I know you already found an answer, but for future readers it would be good to add the actual errors you are getting, so that they can actually *find* your question when they do a web search for it.

Comment: will upload to pastebin and share all the info tonight.

Answer (score 1):

I found this:

```
ffmpeg -i "concat:a01.mxf|b02.mxf" -y -c copy result.mxf
```

and it works. I ended up with a working MXF file that connects both streams.

Found it [here](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/10172/how-to-concatenate-two-mxf-files-with-ffmpeg-preserving-both-audio-channels). I hope this will help someone in the future.